# How to input phone numbers without the leading +1

Tags: django, phone-number

In the PhoneNumber field for django, how do you allow users to input phone numbers without the leading +1 in the beginning?

This will be a form they fill out.

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phoneNumber = PhoneNumberField()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your form code. (If you select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button it will be formatted as code.)

Comment: I dont have code for this because I did not create the PhonNumberField. Its a package I installed. All numbers require a +1 in the beginning.

Comment: I know you didn't create it. But you must be _using it_ somewhere. That's the code I'm asking for.

Comment: I just have a model with that field in it. You want that?

Comment: I want to understand where your users are inputting phone numbers. Are they doing it via the Django admin? What is the name of the model, and what is the name of the field?

Comment: Why did you give me a downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. The person who did probably thought this was too broad (which it might be).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your users are using the Django admin.

First, create a [form for your model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) with a custom `clean_<fieldname>` method that parses the number into E.164 format before storing it.

Something like this should do it (I'm not including the whole class or the imports; this is just a sample `clean_` method):

```
def clean_phoneNumber(self):
    phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phoneNumber']

    # Replace 'US' with whatever type of number it is
    # See https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers
    parsed_number = phonenumbers.parse(phone_number, 'US')

    return phonenumbers.format_number(
        parsed_number,
        phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164,
    )
```

Then create a [model admin class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) for your model and set its `form` to the form you just created.

Aside: Consider using `phone_number` instead of `phoneNumber`. That's much more idiomatic. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).